# How to calculate the average of each key's values from 1 milion struct datas?

Tags: algorithm, struct

I have 1 milion of the following struct:

```
type person struct {
  age     int
  . . .
  //some more attributes like name, surname, etc
}
```

My goal at the end is to know for each person's name the average of its ages. A person may occur multiple times or just 1 time. I read the struct datas one by one, they are random given and I can't sort them.

Example with only *age* and *name* attributes written like a key-value data:

```
Josh: 34
Abigail: 6
Aaron: 43
Josh: 4
Frederich: 22
...
Aaron: 3
...
```

So when I access a data eg Aaron, I don't know how many times he occurs in the given stock of data, maybe that's the only time I see him. At the end I need to know the average of each person's age not necessary in an order.

My idea was the following:

I used a key-values data like this: `map[name]=average, howMany`. When i accessed a data, I  calculated the new average with the new data's age and incremented howMany. Quite straightforward I'd say.

**I can't keep in my RAM 1 milion structs like this.**

I'd appreciate any suggestion and any grammar correction.

Comment: The hashmap idea is good. If you need to update the people set (adding or deleting people), you must store additional data: instead of being the average, the value of your map should be a pair _(total of ages, number of people)_

Comment: This question has too many unknown parameters... like, is the data static (you can calculate them once, up front) or dynamic (need to implement data analysis when name is asked); can you modify the base data structure (for example, sort it on name), is there some sort of database underlying it (SQL could provide the answer in a whim), etc.

Comment: Hi @Jur, data is static and no, I can't sort anything because that would be very slow.

Comment: If all the 1 mil entries have different names, the result should consists of 1 mil averages. Is it prohibited to return the result (a set of averages) in RAM?
Also, how can sorting 1mil entries be "very slow"? Are you doing robotics or high frequency trading? :-)